# Google Places API Autocomplete - How to print "no results" in the dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-places-api

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var options = {types: ['(cities)'], componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}};
    var input = document.getElementById('searching');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, "place_changed", function() {
        document.getElementById('searching').value = "";
        $('#stat-boxes').hide();
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
        var getcityinfo = $.get('/cities', place).done(function(res){
            res = JSON.parse(res);
            var number_sites = (res[0]["count"]);
            var Min_height = (res[0]["min_height"]);
            var Max_height = (res[0]["max_height"]);
            if( number_sites > 0 ){
                $('#num-locations').text(number_sites);
                $('#location-text').text(place);
                if( Min_height && Max_height ){
                    $('#min-max-heights').text(Min_height+"' - "+Max_height+"'");
                } else {
                    $('#min-max-heights').text('Not available');
                }
                $('#stat-boxes').fadeIn();
            } else {
                alert('No results');
            }
```

```html
    <div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider pic-carousel" style="height: 830px;">
            <div class="over-pic carousel-fixed-item center" style="z-index: 1">
                <div class="carousel-control-prev" id="btnPrev"> </div>
                <div class="carousel-control-next" id="btnNext"> </div>
                <input type="text" id="searching">
                <div class="choice-words">
                    <div class="headline">Hello, Welcome to SmallCellSite.com</div>
                    <div class="headline-sub">The largest marketplace for wireless broadband attachments in the US.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#two!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-02.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#three!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-03.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#four!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-04.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item white-text" href="#one!">
                <img src="/img/welcome/scs-home-01.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="stat-boxes" class="stat-boxes-wrapper">
            <div class="stat-box">
                <div class="stat-box-header"><h4>Locations</h4></div>
                <span class="num-locations" id="num-locations">xxx</span>
                <span class="location-text">Assets located in and around</span>
                <span class="location-text" id="location-text">Houston, TX</span>
                <a href="#" class="stat-boxes-link">Municipality Features</a>
            </div>
            <div class="stat-box stat-box-middle">
                <div class="stat-box-header"><h4>Details</h4></div>
                <span class="num-locations" id="min-max-heights">15'-65'</span>
                <span class="location-text">Heights of assets in your search results</span>
                <a href="#" class="stat-boxes-link">Power + Fiber availability</a>
            </div>
            <div class="stat-box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have created a google places autocomplete search box where a user can only search for cities in USA. Everything works fine but now I want to create a new functionality as per following.

Suppose a user types gibberish in the search bar like "ejnfwniefewfneinenfwenefjnew", currently search box stops showing any places for this since no match could be made. But when this happens, I want my dropdown to display only one row displaying message - "No matches found". how can I do that. I read through lot of questions but seems no one has asked for such a feature to be added.

Can someone please explain how to do this and recreate this in code using Javascript and HTMl ?

I am not adding my autocomplete search code because it is fairly general and is mostly as same as the example on google maps website.

Comment: Could you provide some code with which you are rendering the dropdown of your component?

Comment: I assume you get a json response back? I belive the easiest would be to just check if its empty.
As @EugeneTsakh just said, it'd be easier if we could see how you render it.

Comment: @RobinSandström  I just added the javascript function and html tag. See if you can understand and help me.

Comment: @EugeneTsakh To be accurate, I am not rendering the dropdown as of now at all. I am just getting the results in google created autocomplete function through event listener. I actually want to modify the dropdown so that it displays - "No result' if there are no suggestions from google places API.

Comment: @EugeneTsakh I dont know how to check the JSON response. Because I can not figure out how suggestions come and how can I check on that to see if there is no suggestion. Also I can not figure out that if there is no suggestion returned, how can I modify the dropdown to display the custom message.

Comment: What is the value of `number_sites` when you expect it to be 0? If you log it before the if

Comment: @RobinSandström You are slightly misunderstanding here. I am getting user input in 'searching' and I am running google autocomplete functions on that user input string to create suggestions. then user clicks on one city and that city is passing to my database query where I am pulling number of sites (number_sites) in that city. so number_sites is the data coming from database after the suggestion match and query execution. But what I need to do is happening way before that.

Comment: Ahh yes sorry my bad!

So you want another listener on `autocomplete` other than `place_changed`?

Comment: Yes, sort of. I am not sure though how and if that will work. I want a listener which can interact with the suggestions coming from google autocomplete listener and put a message in dropdown if there are no suggestions.


something similar to this fiddle - 

http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/129/

Try giving gibberish input such as - "efefefefefefef"

Comment: You could always render it out and count how many elements with the class of `pac-item` after your input field change if you look at this https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/. Its ugly but might work.
I couldn't find any other events in the documentation sadly.

Sorry that i cant be of more help. But even google is only using the `place_changed`. They just abuse that enter click triggers it in their example codes

Comment: @RobinSandström Thanks for your inputs though your link seems to be broken and gives 404.

Comment: Oh ye https://jsfiddle.net/9oex73md/

Comment: @EugeneTsakh any suggestions or answers ??

Comment: @VibhuSharma are you able to extend your markup with additional tags?

Comment: @EugeneTsakh I just edited the post with additional tags. Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: @EugeneTsakh any suggestions ?

Comment: @RobinSandström Hey, I found a similar answer and its very close to what I wanted to do. Please check the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10517377/6923941

Run the first answer. I just need one help now - Can you display the custom message ( when no result is returned in pac-container class of google autocomplete) in the dropdown rather than showing in InnerHTML ?